# How to hide "VR" button unless VR headset is present on A-Frame scene

Tags: aframe

By default an A-Frame scene shows a "VR" icon to enter immersive VR mode in all cases, even if a headset is not present. Is there a simple way to only show this icon when a user is using a headset with WebXR available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a built in A-Frame function `checkHeadsetConnected()` for this purpose. You can use this in a component attached to the `a-scene` entity to disable `vr-mode-ui` when a headset is not present. Here is example code for this:

```
  // only show VR button if headset connected
  AFRAME.registerComponent('vr-mode-ui-if-headset', {
    dependencies: ['vr-mode-ui'],
    init: function () {
      if (!AFRAME.utils.device.checkHeadsetConnected()) {
        this.el.setAttribute('vr-mode-ui', 'enabled', false);
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is a glitch A-Frame scene showing this component in use:

Code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lapis-wide-cartoon?path=index.html

Live project: https://lapis-wide-cartoon.glitch.me/